# Need clarification of LAN application concept

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, p2p, lan

Recently i developed a simple chat application in java using sockets. It was working fine. But now i want to make an application which can communicate over the Local Area Networks like IPMSG. The features will be

1. message sending.
2. file sending.
3. voice chat.
4. group chat.
5. encryption/decryption on demand.

These were the basic features to be included.

Now the confusion i am facing over here is

- The application is an peer to peer application in which one user can do anything what other users can do.
- There is no centralized server and there in no client. Every node acts as a server and client both.

So the application has to be peer to peer. But when i googled it then i am getting samples like client-server only and when i talk to my peers regarding this then also they suggest me the client-server model but there is no justification for why client-server and why not peer to peer. Am i right in this case ? Can anyone please guide me in this case because once i start development on any of these concept i cannot revert back due to time shortage. Your suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using a client server model modified to support to P2P networking. When a node comes into the network it broadcasts its presence and the other nodes are continuously listening for new nodes. Each node will have their own list for the connected nodes in the network. In case of new node coming into the network they will update their own lists. I am using UDP for all most all the operations except file transfer as it needs to be in TCP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason a server-client relation is advised, is to make it easier for logging, or make a large chatroom for everyone (like IRC). If there is a login required, the server would also verify the login details. So without a server in between, phishing attacks would become more difficult to deal with.

I don't see why a P2P chat wouldn't work, though. If I recall correctly, Skype is doing that. I always love decentralizing. Good luck with your project. :)

Comment: There is no login facility. The application just shows the people in the LAN and they can communicate with each other in the medium they want to communicate.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya Oh sorry, forgot about that part of the title. Well since it's local, I don't really see a problem with anything.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya: That's the point. If you don't have a dedicated server that each client can log into, you have to develop another decentralized method for administering who is online and who is not. In a LAN, for example broadcasting beacon packets is a possible solution.

Comment: @buc : I am not getting what you are trying to say ? Are you saying i have to follow peer to peer concept?

Comment: All I'm saying is that some functions that are easy to implement with a centralized-server-and-clients concept (like for example maintaining the currently online users) may need extra development efforts when following a peer-to-peer achitecture.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) standard and packages that use it like [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) (linux FOSS) or [Bonjour](http://www.macosforge.org/) (Apple & Windows open-source but not GPL). Zeroconf allows for configuration and detection of network services without user interaction or a central configuration server.

Comment: It's probably worth adding that iChat uses Bonjour to do LAN detection for their iChat client.

Comment: Well, i am trying to develop application for all the OS and in java. My question still stands. Which is appropriate Server-Client or Peer-Peer model... :-)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very specific. Zeroconf (used by Bonjour) is used in iChat to do local area network chatting without the need for a centralized server. So if you're running iChat on the same local area network as another machine, it will detect the chat service being ran by that machine and automatically connect to it, allowing you to chat without a centralized server.

Comment: As you have written Bonjour is available for MAC and Windows only, i have to make my application linux compatible also. So can you please give a name of any such api ?

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya As per answer, see [Avahi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi) for Zeroconf support in linux.